# How to constrain a mapped type to only accept string keys when using typescript?

Tags: typescript

I've read in the documentation of Typescript that I can create a mapped type that can be used to constrain the possible keys to the keys of a specific type:

```
type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  [K in keyof Type]: boolean;
};
```

but if I want to have a generic type as a value that only accepts strings:

```
type Key<K extends string> {
    key: K
}
```

then this doesn't work:

```
type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  [K in keyof Type]: Key<K>;
};
```

because

```
Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'keyof Type' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

It seems that I have to constrain the keys in `Type`, but how do I do that?

Comment: You can write `K in string & keyof Type` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzQJ4m) but that prevents the mapped type from being homomorphic (e.g., preserving optionality and `readonly`ness of the properties).  Do you need a homomorphic mapped type?  If not, I'll write up an answer explaining.  If so, please [edit] to demonstrate this need by showing a [mre] including a required input/output pair where it matters.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
type OptionsFlags<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
```

**example usage (success):**

```
type Element = {
  id: string;
  label: string;
};

const data: OptionsFlags<Element> = { id: "username", label: "Username" };

> data
{ id: 'username', label: 'Username' }
```

**example usage (failure):**

```
type Element = {
  id: string;
  label: string;
};

> const data: OptionsFlags<Element> = { name: "username" };
<repl>.ts:11:39 - error TS2322: Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionsFlags<Element>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'OptionsFlags<Element>'.

11 const data: OptionsFlags<Element> = { name: "username" };
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```